# Writing Snappy Parquet from Spark Streaming

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming, parquet, snappy

I am interested in using Snappy Parquet for persisting events using Spark Streaming. 
I am thinking about Parquet's columnar nature, and Snappy's compression and I think that they might not valuable in the case where events are written one at a time, or one micro-batch at a time. 
I have not experience particularly with Snappy and Parquet, but with other compression algorithms and columnar databases, and they both usually need large chunks of data to be effective.
Are my worries justified? What's the general recommendation in this scenario?